# Displaying results from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Not a JavaScript/Node.js/database professional, just trying to understand some basic concepts about Node.js and MongoDB. I got stuck on the following:

I would like to display the query result from mongoDB on a page, but I am unable to do so anywhere else but in console.

This is the module I am using for querying mongodb:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

function getOwner(currentSite){
    const urlM = "xxxx";     
    MongoClient.connect(urlM,{ useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true },function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("TrainingDB");
    dbo.collection("SiteOwners").find({SiteName: currentSite}).toArray(function(err,result){
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result[0].SiteOwner) //this shows correct result
        db.close();
        return result[0].SiteOwner //this doesn't do anything
    })                
});
};

exports.getOwner=getOwner;
```

The console shows the correct result but it doesn't return any value. This is the handler I am using for retrieving the data:

```
var apps = require("./apps");   
     
function site1(response){
        console.log("Request handler 'site1 has been called.")
            response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type": "text/html"});
            response.write("Welcome to Site1</p>The Owner of this site is: "+apps.getOwner("Site1"));
            response.end();
    };
```

`+apps.getOwner("Site1")` returns undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `return` statement does not return anything for the `getOwner` function. Rather it returns for `...function(err,result){`.

I would make your `getOwner` function return a promise that you can resolve in `site1` and get your result:

```
function getOwner(currentSite){
    const urlM = "xxxx";
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      MongoClient.connect(urlM,{ useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true },function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("TrainingDB");
        dbo.collection("SiteOwners").find({SiteName: currentSite}).toArray(function(err,result){
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result[0].SiteOwner) //this shows correct result
            resolve(result[0].SiteOwner)
            db.close();
        })                
      });
    })
}
```

Then, in your `site1` function do this:

```
function site1(response){
    apps.getOwner("Site1")
      .then(result => {
        console.log("Request handler 'site1 has been called.")
        response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        response.write("Welcome to Site1</p>The Owner of this site is: "+result);
        response.end();
      })
};
```

Comment: Is it normal that it takes quite some time till the page loads? Can it be related to the promise?

Comment: @DDEX it's related to the fact that you're opening and closing a database connection on every request. That's a very bad practice as db connections take a long time. Your app needs to make a db connection when you launch it, not when you request a specific page.

Comment: And can you give me a hint how to do that? I was trying to create an instance of MongoClient when the application starts that I would then use in getOwner function but that just doesn't seem to work. The instance is always undefined.

Comment: It's hard to advise you in the comments, but I think this tutorial will give you a pretty good idea: https://medium.com/wesionary-team/create-your-first-rest-api-with-node-js-express-and-mongodb-447fce535385 It's using mongoose, but the principle is the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use like this.

```
  async  function site1(response){
       let result = await apps.getOwner("Site1");

      if(result && result!= null){
            console.log("Request handler 'site1 has been called.")
            response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type": "text/html"});
            response.write("Welcome to Site1</p>The Owner of this site is: 
             "+result);
            response.end();
         }else{
            response.writeHead(404,{"Content-Type": "text/html"});
            response.end();

         }
    }
```